# MySQL IF(SELECT) statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a MySQL statement that's failing to compile, can anyone give me a basic example of how it should work? Semi pseudo-code:

```
IF (SELECT 'id' FROM terms WHERE name = 'thename' IS NULL) THEN
# Do this...
ELSE
# do this...
END IF
```

I just can't get any IF statement to work at all, not even a test one like:

```
IF(1=1) 
THEN SELECT "works"
END IF
```

Comment: Is this a SQL statement or a stored procedure? The form you're using here is only for stored procedures, [as made clear in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html).

Comment: Most probably you are running it as MySQL query.

Comment: Depending on what your "Do this" bit is, you might be better off using the expression form of `IF` rather than the statement form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first example, you're not evaluating the condition. You need to move the `IS NULL` outside the `SELECT`:

```
IF (SELECT 'id' FROM terms WHERE name = 'thename') IS NULL THEN
...
```

If you're running this inside a `SELECT` statement, you may want to use [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT 'id' FROM terms WHERE name = 'thename') IS NULL THEN ...
    END
```

Otherwise, see the [`IF` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html).